# Implementing Hypermedia using flask-restless

Tags: flask, hypermedia, flask-restless

I already have a REST API implemented using flask and the flask-restless extension. To make navigation easier, I wanted to implement Hypermedia-style links.
I can write a postprocessor to insert the links [manually](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customizing.html#request-preprocessors-and-postprocessors) but it feels hacky. Is there a cleaner way or maybe something supported by flask-restless?

Answer (score 0):

Ah just found from https://flask-restless.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html one can use include_methods to include the attributes for Hypermedia.